# Предшествовавший творению мира

Tags: лексика

Добрый день. Скажите, пожалуйста, можно ли заменить прилагательным причастный оборот *предшествовавший творению мира*? Например, в сочетании *предшествовавшая творению мира пустота*. Мне хотелось бы выразить определение прилагательным, но вот что-то не могу подобрать однословного эквивалента. Старею, видно...

Comment: @Noir, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Предвечная, например.

"Верою познаем, что веки (одно из значений - миры) устроены словом Божьим, так что из невидимого произошло видимое" (Евр. 11:3). Под веками здесь подразумевается те времена, которые стали существовать совместно и нераздельно с сотворенными временными тварями, то есть с миром вообще.

Добытийная, доначальная, безначальная, довременная, добиблейская, аморфная.

Можно заменить и всё выражение. Предшествовавшая творению мира пустота = Хаос, Великая пустота.

Comment: Спасибо, @Людмила, мне особенно *добиблейская пустота* нравится. Если продолжить вдохновляться Библией, можно еще произвести на свет божий *дословную пустоту*. Но я боюсь, это выражение только Иоанну Богослову было бы понятно.

Answer (score 0):

Зачем здесь причастие прошедшего времени?
"Предшествующая пустота" - и ничего заменять не надо.

Касательно прилагательного. Думаю, прилагательного с синонимичным значением просто не существует, "предшествовавший", "предшествующий" - изначально причастие, не только по форме, но и по смыслу.

Ну а просто красивое слово с отчасти схожим смыслом найти, конечно, можно, но это уже стилистика, вещь субъективная.